# getting the ranking of the rows in mysql group by ORDER BY statements

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, auto-increment

I have a table with the following fields: season, collection, product_key, aggregated_sale. i want add extra rank column(auto-incremented), which should rank at order by season, collection,aggregated_sale

suppose I have

```
ss, f1, 2, 5
ss, f1, 3, 10
ss, f1, 1, 11
ss, f2, 4, 7
ss, f2, 5, 11
```

expected output is

```
ss, f1, 2, 5,1
ss, f1, 3, 10,2
ss, f1, 1, 11,3
ss, f2, 4, 7,1
ss, f2, 5, 11,2
```

Comment: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

Comment: it is inserting row numbers based on a particular column. but i want based on multiple columns..how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the job, although not so efficient

```
select col1, col2,col3,col4,
(
 select count(*) from myTable where 
  col1<t.col1 or
 (col1=t.col1 and col2<t.col2) or
 (col1=t.col1 and col2=t.col2 and col4<t.col4)
)+1 as col5
FROM myTable t
order by col1,col2
```

Notes:

- You need to specify what your ranking should be when 2 records are identical
- You need to use the UPDATE if you want to save the result in your table
- ORDER BY is optional
- In sql server there is a built-in function [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the following query solved my problem

```
set @type = '';
set @num  = 1;
select
   ap.*,
   @num := if(@type = concat(collection,forecast_name), @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
   @type := concat(collection,forecast_name) as dummy
from rank_processing.aggregate_product ap;
```